# How can we do Multiple Operations using Single RecordSet?

Tags: vb.net, adodb

I have some task regarding do operations on database using ADODB in Vb.NET. Can any help me regarding using the same record set multiple times?

I have tried on this topic just by closing the recordset after performing First operation and doing second operation e.t.c.
Example:

```
 Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset()
  OpenConnection()
  rs.Open("table1")
  //Some Operations 
  //Now using same recordSet for Second Operation
  rs.Close()
  rs.Open("table2")
```

In ADO.NET we have "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" in ConnectionString for SqlDataReader.Do we have any property like this in ADODB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more similar thing that exists in ADODB is sending multiple queries in your Sql String then proccessing them one by one using **rs.NextRecordset** (rs is the Recordset), here is an example: [ADO NextRecordset Method Demonstration](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=3058)

But, personally, i prefer doing it as you're doing it now, using just one recordset for each query. Take into account that using multiple recordsets inside one, like in the previous example may require some additional commands in some dbs to ensure no additional unwanted recordsets are created from messages coming from the backend, for example for Sql Server it's a good idea using:

**Set NoCount On** and **Set ANSI_Warnings OFF**